# Взаимодействие WindowsForm C# и DLL написанной на С#

Tags: c#, dll

Программа на С# загружает динамическую библиотеку написанную на том же С# .Соответственно dll выполняет одну только функцию.Появляется простое диалоговое окно,та же форма ,на которой есть одна кнопка.Как сделать так что при нажатии на кнопку программа получила информацию что произошло событие или какое иное действие.Время нажатие может быть неизвестно.

Comment: dll вами написана? в смысле у вас есть доступ к ее коду и вы его можете менять или нет?

Comment: Все будем писать сами.Не понятен алгоритм самого взаимодействия.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам нужно реализовать плагинную систему. Ищите по терминам MEF/MAF - документации много. Также читайте Рихтера - в одной из глав он описал простую реализацию.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется события. Делаю две формы, можно их разнести по разным сборкам, можно в одном приложении, логика от этого не изменится, вам только в случае двух сборок надо будет добавить ссылку из основного приложения на dll и в коде класса главной формы прописать using с указанием пространства имен из сборки.

Итак, по шагам:

1. Создаем вторую форму (у меня это Form2) на которой размещаю TextBox и Button. Внешний вид формы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Двойной клик на кнопке, чтобы перейти к коду и пишем следующее (обратите внимание на объявление события event):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event Action<String> OnSendText;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnSendText?.Invoke(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

2. На главную форму приложения я помещаю ListBox и кнопку, внешний вид будет вот такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Двойной клик на кнопке и пишем следующий код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.OnSendText += Form_OnSendText;
        form.Show();
    }

    private void Form_OnSendText(string obj)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

3. Запускаем, нажимаем на кнопку первой формы, во второй форме вводим текст, нажимаем кнопку на второй форме и видим, что текст появился на первой форме, хотя вторая про нее абсолютно ничего не знает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подписаться на событие,я об этом тоже думал.Но"вам только в случае двух сборок надо будет добавить ссылку из основного приложения на dll и в коде класса главной формы прописать using с указанием пространства имен из сборки."Вот в этом у меня и не стыковка.Опыта мало обойти пока не могу.Дело в том что dll будет загружаться по сети.в этом проблем нет.Как мне ее связать с первым приложением"?Как прописать через using?или я что то все таки не понимаю.Как основное приложение подписать к событию другого?В данном случае к этой dll

Comment: Можно воспользоваться фреймоврком для плагинов, как вам советовали выше или вот здесь посмотрите: https://losev-al.blogspot.com/2009/06/blog-post_23.html

Comment: Спасибо,рассмотрю материал по ссылке.

Comment: Очень интересно.Если возникнут вопросы я могу их Вам по задавать.Сейчас рассмотрю все более внимательно. Вопросы задавать можно где?

Comment: Если по тому коду, что в ответе, то здесь. Если по тому коду, что по ссылке, можно отдельным топиком здесь, и вам, возможно, отвечу не только я. Ну или в комментариях по той ссылке что я вам дал.

Answer (score 0):

В Dll создаю класс MyForm

```
public class MyForm
{
    public event Action<String> OnSend;
    public void Launch()
    {

        ClassLibrary1.FormTest frm = new ClassLibrary1.FormTest();
        frm.OnSendText += Form_OnSendText;
        frm.Show();
    }
    private void Form_OnSendText(string obj)
    {

        OnSend?.Invoke(obj);

    }
}
```

Форма FormTest имеет кнопку и текстовое поле .При загрузке dll  вызываем метод Launch где делаем описанные действия по коду.
Основное приложение имеет форму ,кнопку и лист бокс.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ListBox list;
        Button button;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list = new ListBox();
            list.Location = new Point(5, 10);
            list.Size = new Size(275, 225);
            list.Name = "list";
            this.Controls.Add(list);
            button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(207, 237);
            button.Name = "button";
            button.Size = new Size(75, 23);
            button.Text = "Нажать";
            button.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Assembly a = Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1");//dll расположенная в папке с приложением
            object obj = a.CreateInstance("MyForm");
            Type t = a.GetType("MyForm");
            MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("Launch");
            mi.Invoke(obj, null);
            EventInfo mi1 = t.GetEvent("OnSend");


        }
        private void OnSendText(string obj)
        {
            list.Items.Add(obj);

        }
    }
}
```

Ни как не могу понять ,как же мне подписаться на событие в dll.Какие есть мысли по этому поводу?Опыта совсем нет.